# Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice not print immeidately

Tags: error, magento-1, messages

I have an observer which will get the date parameter, if the date format is wrong, there is a notice will be print

```
public function datefilter($observer) {

    //$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
    //var_dump($request);
    $order = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order');
    //echo $order;
    if ($order == "range") {

        $start_date = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('start_date');
        $end_date = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('end_date');

        $dir = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('dir');
        //var_dump($start_date);    
        echo $start_date."<br>";
        echo $end_date."<br>";

        if ($this->checkDate($start_date) == false || $this->checkDate($end_date)  == false) {
            echo "Error<br>";
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('bad date');

        } else {

                            $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $start_date, 'to' => $end_date))
            ->load();
        }

    }
}
```

The `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('bad date');` will not print immediately, I need to click the URL in browser can press enter to reenter to page to show.

Comment: what event are you observing?

Comment: catalog_block_product_list_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug.
This is how flash/session messaging works.
You set a message on one request and it is shown in the next one.
Or at least you have to set the session message before the page is rendered in order to be shown on the page.
The event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` is dispatched right before the product collection should be shown.
But by that time, the page section that shows the session messages is already rendered and it cannot render your notice.

You should try to observe a different event, something that is fired before the page is rendered. for example `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view`

Comment: i've updated my question, but if i use controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view, the page will blank if two date are right.

Comment: @hkguile. Oh yeah. You are right. you cannot use that event, but You cannot use `catalog_block_product_list_collection` because of what I explained.

Comment: can i redirect to a page with notice message?